# More than event trigger same method

Tags: angular

```
<div class="someClass" (mouseout, mouseover)="someMethod()"></div>
```

when i use this syntax i have error

```
ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '(mouseout,' is not a valid attribute name.
```

but when split this event  in that way, works fine

```
<div class="someClass" (mouseout)="someMethod()" (mouseover)="someMethod()"</div>
```

How to shorten syntax without having error?

Comment: You can't, that syntax is not supported and there is no easy way to shorten it like that. You could do something similar in the component code (type script) where you could register multiple events in a loop but that is a lot more code than what you would write here in the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, technically, you could create a directive with a [**`@HostListener`**](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) on the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events.

And then expose an `@Output` property from it to call your Component function.

Something like this:

Directive:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appListener]'
})
export class ListenerDirective {

  @Output() appListener: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('mouseover')
  onMouseOver(event) {
    this.appListener.emit(event);
  }

  @HostListener('mouseout')
  onMouseOut(event) {
    this.appListener.emit(event);
  }

}
```

And your Component Template:

```
<div (appListener)="someFunction($event)">
  Here is some text in the DIV
</div >
```

---

> Here's a **[Working Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/listening-to-multiple-events-in-angular)** for your ref.